# Does the overline in the expression functions as a vinculum or something else?

Tags: notation, terminology

**$a - [ a - \{ a - (a - \overline{{a - 1}})\}]$**

*If the overline functions as a vinculum, the value of this expression should be -* 
$a + 1$

*Is it correct?*

Could anybody please help me to understand this?

Comment: The overline seems to mean complex conjugate. I am almost sure it is so

Comment: Per the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)), an overline is called a "vinculum" no matter what it means. Presumably you mean one used for priority of operations. But that is going to depend on context. Apparently it was commonly used for prioritizing in the past, but I have never seen it used for that in anything written in the 20th or 21st century. In an algebraic context such as this, i would most likely expect it to mean a conjugate - in particular, the complex conjugate.